# Value injected with dagger is null

Tags: android, dagger

I'm new to dagger and I'm trying to study it by playing around and creating small Android app.
I have an Application class like this:

```
class App extends Application {
  @Override onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new AppModule(this));
    objectGraph.inject(this);
  }
}
```

and module like this:

```
@dagger.Module(injects = {App.class, MainActivity.class})
public class AppModule {
  private App app;
  public AppModule(App app) { this.app = app; }
  @Provides @Singleton App provideApp(){ return app; }
}
```

and Activity where app is injected:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Inject App app;

  @Override onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(app == null)
      Toast.makeText(this, "app is null", 1000).show();
  }
}
```

My App is assigned in manifest file and breakpoints int `App.onCreate()` are triggered.

Did I miss something ? Can anybody tell me why is it null ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'MainActivity' needs to call ObjectGraph#Inject method which was created in your application.

You can check this: https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-simple or this https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs

Comment: Weird, in my case one class got the injected members fine, while another didn't.  Both are served by ObjectGraph.